# What Are Some Ways I Should I Practice to Improve Overall Tone on a Trumpet

Tags: practice, trumpet

So I've been playing trumpet for three years now, and I was wondering what tecniques I should practice to have a better tone quality when playing. How do professional musicians sound so well, and what kind of things do they do to achieve the quality of tone they have.

P.S. I understand that most of this is practice related, but I would appreciate some ways to practice rather than a "with practice" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Long notes, at all dynamic levels, with and without cresc/dim.   Lip slurs.  An efficient embouchure - mouthpiece position, jaw position, minimum pressure.  You'll probably need your teacher's input with this last one.

Comment: Agree on the teacher suggestion. As well as on "minimum pressure". in my experience, the typical error of the early trumpet player is the "press and smile" embouchure. It will create a thin tone. What you want to aim for is relaxed, very little pressure and the corners of the mouth in and down (quite contrary to smile). A good teacher is what helps to find that position.